# remove / add class based on match digit

Tags: javascript, match

i'm struggling with the remove/add class when there is no digit in the address field. When there is no digit in the field the class: 'ok-form' has te be removed and the class : 'error-form' has to be added.

If i just add `$(this).removeClass('ok-form').addClass('error-form');` after this part (line12): `if (!$(this).val().match(/\d+/)) {` it is not working.

Does anyone has an idea?

```
 $('input[name="shipping_address[address1]"], input[name="payment_address[address1]"]').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('ok-form error-form');
        if ($(this).siblings('.supercheckout-required').css('display') == "none" && $(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).removeClass('ok-form error-form');
        } else if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).removeClass('ok-form').addClass('error-form');
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="errorsmall">' + required_error + '</span>');
        } else if (!validateAddress($(this).val())) {
            $(this).removeClass('ok-form').addClass('error-form');
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="errorsmall">' + invalid_address + '</span>');
        } else if (validateAddress($(this).val())) {
            if (!$(this).val().match(/\d+/)) {
                if (!$(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').length)
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="warningsmall">' + street_number_warning + '</span>');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').remove();
            }
            $(this).removeClass('error-form').addClass('ok-form');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final line in that block removes the error form class and adds the OK form class back, making the line you're trying to add essentially a no-op:

```js
else if (validateAddress($(this).val())) {
    if (!$(this).val().match(/\d+/)) {
        // we try swapping classes
        $(this).removeClass('ok-form').addClass('error-form');
        if (!$(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').length)
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="warningsmall">' + street_number_warning + '</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').remove();
    }
    // this line undoes the class changes
    $(this).removeClass('error-form').addClass('ok-form');
}
```

In fact, if you step through your code in the debugger, you'll see the class switches, and then switches back when it reaches the end of the block.

If you're not familiar using the debugger, I highly recommend looking into it, as it can be a great help when facing problems such as this one:

- Chrome Debugger guide: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript (specifically, look into the "Pause in Debugger" section)

---

There are many ways you could solve this. One way would be to keep a boolean around in that block, and then set the classes according to its value at the end:

```js
else if (validateAddress($(this).val())) {
    let isErrorState = false;
    if (!$(this).val().match(/\d+/)) {
        isErrorState = true;
        if (!$(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').length)
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="warningsmall">' + street_number_warning + '</span>');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.warningsmall').remove();
    }

    // swap classes

    if (isErrorState) {
        $(this).removeClass('ok-form').addClass('error-form');
    }
    else {
         $(this).removeClass('error-form').addClass('ok-form');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Also thank you for the advice to use the debugger guide.